# python script equivalent to sed command

Tags: python, sed

I have sed command : sed -r 's/^((.){20})/\n/' log1.txt
which ignores first 20 charcters of file log1.txt.
what is the pythonic equivalent to this sed command??

Comment: Well just look for an example of how to do a regex(search and replace rather than just match) in Python then change that regex to the one you have.

Comment: and look up how to read a file into a variable

Comment: a regex example in python `re.sub("a","z","abc")`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure entirely, but I would imagine it would go something like this:

```
with open('log1.txt', 'r') as f:
    l = f.readlines() 
    contents = ''.join(l) 
    print contents[20:]
```

After opening, the first line copies the entirety of log1.txt into list items under `l`. These are joined back together into a single string in `contents`, and then the last line only returns contents after the 20th character to the end.

Enclosing it all using `with` keeps you from having to run `f.close()` on the log1.txt after all is said and done.